# Branch cuts of $f(z)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+z^4}}$

Tags: complex-analysis, branch-cuts, branch-points

Let $f(z)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+z^4}}$. The branch points are $e^{\frac{2k-1}{4}\pi i}$. I am going to find ALL possible branch cuts.

When $z$ traces a closed curve (anticlockwise) around any of the above branch points, the complex number $1+z^4$ also traces a closed curve around the origin. Therefore, the argument of $f$ increases by $\pi$. So we can cut $\mathbb C$ by four curves connecting each branch point to $\infty$.

Question: Are there any other ways to arrange those branch cuts? For example, I find the cuts by the intervals $[-e^{\pi i/4},e^{\pi i/4}]$ and $\{z\in\mathbb C:\arg z=\frac{3}{4} \pi\}$ also possible. **How can I find ALL possible ways to do the branch cut?**

I hope that the answer can be more formal and rigorous than what I do above.

Comment: You should find the monodromy group : how $f$ transforms under analytic continuation along closed-loops $\gamma \subset \Bbb{C} - (-1)^{1/4}$, it is locally analytic and a domain where it is globally analytic is any open not containing any closed loop with non-trivial monodromy.

Comment: $\arg z = 3 \pi/4$ gives a ray, not a line, so that cannot be correct. The multi-valued function $f$ can assume only two different values for each $z$. Going once around any one of the four branch points ($\infty$ is not a branch point) swaps those two values. Now suppose $\gamma_{i j}$ is a curve indefinitely approaching the branch points $z_i$ and $z_j$. Show that any of
$$\gamma_{12} \cup \gamma_{34}, \\
\gamma_{13} \cup \gamma_{24}, \\
\gamma_{14} \cup \gamma_{23}$$
is a valid choice of the branch cuts.