# Do branch cuts always connect branch points?

Tags: complex-analysis, branch-cuts, branch-points

While doing some exercises on complex functions, I noticed that every time I find a branch cut in the complex plane it is always in between two branch points, such as in the function

\begin{equation}
f(z) = \sqrt{z} \quad \text{for }\; z\in\mathbb{C} 
\end{equation}

where there are two branch points, in $0$ and at $\infty$, and there's a branch starting a the origin and then going to $\infty$.
Another example could be the function

\begin{equation}
g(z) = \sqrt{(z+1)(z-1)} \quad \text{for }\; z\in\mathbb{C} 
\end{equation}

where the branch points are in $\pm 1$ and there's a branch cut connecting the two of them. Is this always true?
If that's the case, can the inverse be said, meaning that given two branch points there's always a branch connecting them? And if this is true, what am I to do in the event of a function having more than two branch points? Does this also mean that there's no function with a single branch point? (Note that I've never encountered such a function, so I suspect that this is true)

Also, note that I know how to figure out if there's a branch in a certain area of the plane, I'm asking whether this things can be affirmed prior to calculations.

Sorry for the number of questions but I thought it would've been appropriate to ask them all in the same thread.
There's an example of connecting 4 branch points in a comment in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3494664/branch-cuts-of-fz-frac1-sqrt1z4) thread, even though it might not be the same.

Comment: Another example $f(x) = ((z+1)(z-1))^{1/3}$ with three branch points at $1, -1, \infty$.  Also consider $(e^z)/\sqrt{z}$ with branch point at $0$ but is $\infty$ considered to be a branch point or an essential singularity or what?

Comment: @GEdgar $e^{z} / \sqrt{z}$ has a branch point in $0$ and at $\infty$ indeed